# Partitioning items of a backbone.js collection (for grouped rendering)

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

Let's say, I have a backbone.js model named `Item` that is stored in an `ItemCollection`. Given that `Item` has an attribute `date`, what would be the best approach to partition `ItemCollection` so that all items sharing the same date end up in the same partition?

Ultimately, the partitioned data structure is supposed back a (backbone.js) view that is supposed to render the items grouped by date.

What would be the best approach for this?

So far I considered

1. dynamically extracting the partitions when the index view is rendered, but that would probably break the elegance of backbone's event-based mechanism to render collection / model updates.
2. representing each grouping header as an instance of a `Header` model and attaching a collection with its partition to it. I would somehow need to keep the partitions attached to the `Header` instances in sync with the main `ItemCollection`, but that's probably manageable through backbone's eventing mechanism.

Would any of these approaches make sense? Any other ideas?

P.S.: The grouping structure does not exist in my backend data model (and I would like to avoid introducing it), so this is some mapping that needs to happen on the fly on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a hybrid of your two options would be workable. I would probably approach this as follows:

1. Instead of `Header`, you can have an `ItemGroup` model (a little more descriptive) that renders the `Item`s inside of its `collection`, which would be a partition of the larger `ItemCollection`.
2. The partitioning itself can be done when you render the parent view, which I'll call `AppView`. In `AppView#render`, partition the data as you want. (You didn't explicitly ask *how* to partition the data, but you can use Underscore to do that in a few lines of code.)
3. Bind `AppView#render` to the `add` and `remove` event of `ItemCollection`, so that whenever a new item is added, the partitions re-render themselves.